# compgen : ignoring case

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement a custom **bash completion** as [described here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/317). However, it seems that `compgen` is **case-sensitive**. Is there a way to turn it **case-insensitive** in that context ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would modify the example from the link you mentioned into something like this:

```
_foo() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD],,}"     # this downcases the result
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1],,}"  # here too
    opts="--help --verbose --version"

    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _foo foo
```

For more info refer to the bash documentation or the [bash hackers site](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification).

Comment: But this hinges on the fact that `opts` is all lower case. If it was `--help --verbose --VERSION`, it could never complete the third case.